# Where to ask if a simulation is correctly performed?

Tags: support

I've done a simulation with R and would like to post it on my blog explaining the steps I took.

The program simulates a player playing at a famous game and is aimed at estimating the probability of winning but I'm not sure it is correct and cannot check it using google because I changed some basics assumptions and therefore should get a different answer. Normally I would check it myself by hand, but I got a result I cannot explain and therefore I would like to hear someone else's opinion on the hypothesis, the process and the conclusion before post it on my blog.

Would it be on topic to ask it on cross validated? Is there a better statistics site to ask this?

Comment: @Glen_b the last solution you suggested seems to be the best one for this kind of problem although I'm more confident about the code and more worried about flaws in the methodology. If you answer the question I'll mark your answer as accepted since you solved my problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If framed as "please check my code" it's probably going to be seen as off topic here (that may fly at say codereview; or stackoverflow might accept it depending on how it's presented).

If framed as a question about the methodology to solve a probability problem (rather than inherently a code problem), it might be seen as more nearly on topic here. (For an explanation of what kind of code related questions *can* be asked, see the [help/on-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

If you break it into two questions ("is this a correct approach to solving the probability problem" and "does this code correctly implement the approach" you may be able to get each answered in different places).